# Cannot iterate through two different collections simultaneously c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm Working in ASP.NET MVC and i'm trying to combine two collections to execute in one loop i have tried ZIP method but it doesn't return anything if one collection is empty. I tried Concat Method but it is givning this error

```
System.Collection.Generic.ICollection<Project.Entities.TDetail> does not contains definition for 'Concat'.
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public virtual ICollection<TDetail> Details { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<TRequest> Requests { get; set; } 
}
```

My Loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Details.Concat(Model.Requests))
{
}
```

ZIP Method Tried But Failed:

```
var request = Model.Requests.ToList();
var details = Model.Details.ToList();
var final = details.Zip(request, (x, y) => new { Detail = x, Request = y });
@foreach (var item in final)
{
}
```

I have spent my 3 days on this but couldn't find any solution, please help me with this.

Comment: It may help if you post example input and desired output.

Comment: @dav_i i want to display results from these two collections, Requests and Details together.

Comment: @Usama dav_i is asking what the desired output/html should be because you can very easily run two different loops (one for each list) and still potentially get the result you want.

Comment: How are they related?  Is there a key value you can join on?  Or do you just want to list them in order side by side?

Comment: @DStanley i just want to list them side by side, there is no relationship between them

Comment: @Henrik what is TBase? what i need to put there?

Comment: @Usama Then I would not try to loop them at the same time - loop them separately, creating two different UI elements (list?  table? span?) and use styling to show them side-by-side.

Comment: @DStanley you're right i have did the same before, but requirement is to combine them in a single html table. Moreover both collections have different properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i just want to list them side by side, there is no relationship between them

Then neither `Concat` or `Zip` will work for you.  `Concat` will append items to a list ("vertically"). `Zip` will give you "side-by-side" collections, but will only give you as many elements as the *shortest* collection.

You could do a straight `for` loop:

```
var requests = Model.Requests.ToList();
var details = Model.Details.ToList();
var length = Math.Max(requests.Count, details.Count);
@for(int i=0 ; i< length ; i++)
{
    if(i <= request.Count)
    {
       var request = requests[i];
       @: html code here
    }
    if(i <= details.Count)
    {
       var detail = deatils[i]
       @: html code here
    }
}
```

Or loop separately and create two different UI elements, using styling to place them side-by-side

```
var requests = Model.Requests.ToList();
var details = Model.Details.ToList();
@foreach (var item in requests)
{
     @: html code here
}
@foreach (var item in details)
{
     @: html code here
}
```